# OnSelectedIndexChanged on a GridView's ItemTemplate not firing

Tags: asp.net, itemtemplate

I have a `GridView` with some `ItemTemplate` and I need to work with the `SelectedIndexChanged` event... I manually wrote the codes but it's not working... Check it out:

`HTML` code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PROJETO" HeaderStyle-Width="90px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Font-Size="12px">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:DropDownList ID="Drop_Projetos" Width="115px" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Drop_Projetos_SelectedIndexChanged" EnableViewState="false"
          AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And here's my `codebehind`, where I've put a `breakpoint` but it isn't even fired...

```
protected void Drop_Projetos_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //SomeCode
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add to the DropDownList:

```
AutoPostBack="true"
```

Then it will post back to the server.

Comment: I just did, but now the value that is already in the `DropDownList` vanish ! And it's not going to my breakpoint ;s

Comment: Are you binding data to the grid?  With `EnableViewState="false"`, this will never remember any of the values bound.  If they are static, I believe this would be OK, but with viewstate off, the selected value would never be retained.  Try removing that and see if it works.

Comment: WORKED MAN :D Thanks a Bunch !!I Just `removed` the `EnableViewState=false`

Answer (score 1):

Missing autopostback in the drop down list `AutoPostBack="true"`

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Drop_Projetos" Width="115px" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true"
 OnSelectedIndexChanged="Drop_Projetos_SelectedIndexChanged" EnableViewState="false">    
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

### Edit 1

Here is a similar question which may help you

[How can I add cascading drop downs inside of a gridview for edits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754823/how-can-i-add-cascading-drop-downs-inside-of-a-gridview-for-edits)

[Implementing cascading DropDownList binding in a templated control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749944/implementing-cascading-dropdownlist-binding-in-a-templated-control)

Comment: I just did, but now the value that is already in the DropDownList vanish ! And it's not going to my breakpoint ;s

Comment: @Ghaleon what do you want to do on selected index changed?

Comment: When I change the selected item/value of my Drop_Projetos, I want to bind a new data to my `other DropDownList`. I have two, when I change the value of the first, I want to rebind the data of the second... Bcause the items on the second `DDL` changes according to the selected item of the first one. You got it ?

Comment: +1 Because I forgot the `AutoPostBack = true` could you explain to me how does this attribut really works?

Comment: If you do post-back the your old binding to the grid will be lost. As you might be binding inside `if(!Page.IsPostBack)`